# Get only IP adresses from arp

Tags: c#, bash, cmd

I am making an app, and for one of its functions i need to get ip adresses of my network.

`ping 192.168.1.255 & arp-a` will list every ip adress i need, in format of table :

```
 Internet Address      Physical Address      Type

  192.168.x.x           xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx     dynamic   
  192.168.x.x           xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
```

Code for that goes something like this :

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string strCmdText3;
                strCmdText3 = "/c ping 192.168.1.255 & arp -a";

                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText3;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();
                //* Read the output (or the error)
                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                //Console.WriteLine(output);
                //string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                //Console.WriteLine(err);
                process.WaitForExit();

                show.Text = output;
            }
```

Now what i don't know is how can i get only the IP Addresses (put them into array or something), so i can use them later for different commands.

this how out will be

```
"\r\nPinging 192.168.1.255 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\nRequest timed out.\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 192.168.1.255:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),\r\n\r\nInterface: 10.10.10.74 --- 0x7\r\n  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type\r\n  10.10.80.1            10-da-43-72-3a-99     dynamic   \r\n  10.10.80.335           00-e0-4c-c7-44-0c     dynamic   \r\n  10.10.80.290           e0-ac-cb-60-88-c4     dynamic   \r\n  10.10.80.25           34-02-86-a0-79-72     dynamic   \r\n  10.10.80.27           00-1c-c0-8a-59-e7     dynamic   \r\n
```

Comment: An exact example of 'string output' variable would be heplful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Removed the `PING` command, you could add back in but more lines to skip later.
- Split the returned text into a string[] on the new-line character
- Grab and Trim characters 3-18 of each line and put into List

For the most part there was very little needed, here is the updated code

```
static void Main() {
    string strCmdText3;
    strCmdText3 = "/c arp -a";

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText3;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.Start();
    //* Read the output (or the error)
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    //Console.WriteLine(output);
    //string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    //Console.WriteLine(err);
    process.WaitForExit();

    //show.Text = output;

    string[] LinesReturned = output.Split( '\n' );
    List<string> ipAddresses = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 3; i < LinesReturned .GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
    ipAddresses.Add(LinesReturned [i].Substring(2, 15).Trim());
}
```